# How to remove results drawer from emacs jupyter?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, eval, jupyter, code

I am using emacs-jupyter (commit - 16cbda79167b4e2f2c6b61b218658f0f660d97f9 [otherwise I get an [error](https://github.com/emacs-jupyter/jupyter/issues/489)]) on emacs-29.1 and org-9.7pre.

My default header arguments are...

```
org-babel-default-header-args:jupyter-python 
=> ((:display . "plain")
    (:results . "replace both")
    (:session . "jpy")
    (:async . "yes")
    (:pandoc . "t")
    (:exports . "both")
    (:cache . "no")
    (:noweb . "no")
    (:hlines . "no")
    (:tangle . "no")
    (:eval . "never-export")
    (:kernel . "python3"))
org-babel-default-header-args:jupyter-R 
=> ((:display . "plain")
    (:results . "replace both")
    (:session . "jpR")
    (:async . "yes")
    (:pandoc . "t")
    (:exports . "both")
    (:cache . "no")
    (:noweb . "no")
    (:hlines . "no")
    (:tangle . "no")
    (:eval . "never-export")
    (:kernel . "ir"))
```

My issue is that I do not like that certain result blocks get placed in `:results:` drawers, eg...

```
#+begin_src R :display
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + geom_point()
#+end_src
```

returns...

```
#+RESULTS: test image
:RESULTS:
#+attr_org: :width 420 :height 420
[[file:./.ob-jupyter/4d17df235fc5cc4fae3fcdf15c2249b4126f1745.png]]
:END:
```

Is there a way that I can remove these results drawer? I have not tried anything since I do not know where to start regarding this issue.

Comment: You can add `:results raw` to the header. However, new results get added when evaluating the code block repeatedly.